# Google Earth KML altitude modes

Tags: kml, google-earth

I have a problem with google earth’s kml files. When I use the altitude mode `clampToGround` it does perfectly what I expected it to do, it follows the ground nicely.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"    xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
    <Document>
        <name>pm1kml</name>
        <Style id="poly">
            <LineStyle>
                <color>a000ff00</color>
            </LineStyle>
            <PolyStyle>
                <color>a000ff00</color>
        </PolyStyle>
    </Style>
    <Placemark>
        <styleUrl>#poly</styleUrl>
        <Polygon>
            <extrude>0</extrude>
            <tessellate>0</tessellate>
            <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
            <outerBoundaryIs>
                <LinearRing>
                    <coordinates>-5.255885800498265,36.11513548688032,123 -5.257614986927059,36.097578762436825,123 -5.257614986927059,36.097578762436825,123 -5.262736094548725,36.08069673306777,123 -5.262736094548725,36.08069673306777,123 -5.27105232206931,36.06513816569425,123 -5.27105232206931,36.06513816569425,123 -5.282244081528993,36.051500967335095,123 -5.282244081528993,36.051500967335095,123 -5.29588127988815,36.04030920787541,123 -5.29588127988815,36.04030920787541,123 -5.311439847261665,36.03199298035483,123 -5.311439847261665,36.03199298035483,123 -5.3283218766307225,36.02687187273316,123 -5.3283218766307225,36.02687187273316,123 -5.345878601074219,36.02514268630436,123 -5.345878601074219,36.02514268630436,123 -5.363435325517715,36.02687187273316,123 -5.363435325517715,36.02687187273316,123 -5.380317354886772,36.03199298035483,123 -5.380317354886772,36.03199298035483,123 -5.395875922260288,36.04030920787541,123 -5.395875922260288,36.04030920787541,123 -5.409513120619445,36.051500967335095,123 -5.409513120619445,36.051500967335095,123 -5.4207048800791275,36.06513816569425,123 -5.4207048800791275,36.06513816569425,123 -5.429021107599713,36.08069673306777,123 -5.429021107599713,36.08069673306777,123 -5.434142215221378,36.097578762436825,123 -5.434142215221378,36.097578762436825,123 -5.435871401650172,36.11513548688032,123 -5.435871401650172,36.11513548688032,123 -5.434142215221378,36.132692211323814,123 -5.434142215221378,36.132692211323814,123 -5.429021107599713,36.14957424069287,123 -5.429021107599713,36.14957424069287,123 -5.4207048800791275,36.16513280806639,123 -5.4207048800791275,36.16513280806639,123 -5.409513120619445,36.178770006425545,123 -5.409513120619445,36.178770006425545,123 -5.395875922260288,36.18996176588523,123 -5.395875922260288,36.18996176588523,123 -5.380317354886771,36.19827799340581,123 -5.380317354886771,36.19827799340581,123 -5.363435325517715,36.20339910102748,123 -5.363435325517715,36.20339910102748,123 -5.345878601074219,36.205128287456276,123 -5.345878601074219,36.205128287456276,123 -5.3283218766307225,36.20339910102748,123 -5.3283218766307225,36.20339910102748,123 -5.311439847261665,36.19827799340581,123 -5.311439847261665,36.19827799340581,123 -5.29588127988815,36.18996176588523,123 -5.29588127988815,36.18996176588523,123 -5.282244081528993,36.178770006425545,123 -5.282244081528993,36.178770006425545,123 -5.27105232206931,36.16513280806639,123 -5.27105232206931,36.16513280806639,123 -5.262736094548725,36.14957424069287,123 -5.262736094548725,36.14957424069287,123 -5.257614986927059,36.132692211323814,123 -5.257614986927059,36.132692211323814,123 -5.255885800498265,36.11513548688032,123 -5.255885800498265,36.11513548688032,123 -5.255885800498265,36.11513548688032,123  </coordinates>
                </LinearRing>
            </outerBoundaryIs>
        </Polygon>
    </Placemark>
</Document>
```

When I work with `relativeToGround` however, only the outer vertices follow the ground. In the middle of the circle the rock is above the green area and not 123 meters beneath it. 

Image: http://nl.tinypic.com/r/2vcsvq1/8

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"    xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
    <Document>
        <name>pm1kml</name>
        <Style id="poly">
            <LineStyle>
                <color>a000ff00</color>
            </LineStyle>
            <PolyStyle>
                <color>a000ff00</color>
        </PolyStyle>
    </Style>
    <Placemark>
        <styleUrl>#poly</styleUrl>
        <Polygon>
            <extrude>0</extrude>
            <tessellate>0</tessellate>
            <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
            <outerBoundaryIs>
                <LinearRing>
                    <coordinates>-5.255885800498265,36.11513548688032,123 -5.257614986927059,36.097578762436825,123 -5.257614986927059,36.097578762436825,123 -5.262736094548725,36.08069673306777,123 -5.262736094548725,36.08069673306777,123 -5.27105232206931,36.06513816569425,123 -5.27105232206931,36.06513816569425,123 -5.282244081528993,36.051500967335095,123 -5.282244081528993,36.051500967335095,123 -5.29588127988815,36.04030920787541,123 -5.29588127988815,36.04030920787541,123 -5.311439847261665,36.03199298035483,123 -5.311439847261665,36.03199298035483,123 -5.3283218766307225,36.02687187273316,123 -5.3283218766307225,36.02687187273316,123 -5.345878601074219,36.02514268630436,123 -5.345878601074219,36.02514268630436,123 -5.363435325517715,36.02687187273316,123 -5.363435325517715,36.02687187273316,123 -5.380317354886772,36.03199298035483,123 -5.380317354886772,36.03199298035483,123 -5.395875922260288,36.04030920787541,123 -5.395875922260288,36.04030920787541,123 -5.409513120619445,36.051500967335095,123 -5.409513120619445,36.051500967335095,123 -5.4207048800791275,36.06513816569425,123 -5.4207048800791275,36.06513816569425,123 -5.429021107599713,36.08069673306777,123 -5.429021107599713,36.08069673306777,123 -5.434142215221378,36.097578762436825,123 -5.434142215221378,36.097578762436825,123 -5.435871401650172,36.11513548688032,123 -5.435871401650172,36.11513548688032,123 -5.434142215221378,36.132692211323814,123 -5.434142215221378,36.132692211323814,123 -5.429021107599713,36.14957424069287,123 -5.429021107599713,36.14957424069287,123 -5.4207048800791275,36.16513280806639,123 -5.4207048800791275,36.16513280806639,123 -5.409513120619445,36.178770006425545,123 -5.409513120619445,36.178770006425545,123 -5.395875922260288,36.18996176588523,123 -5.395875922260288,36.18996176588523,123 -5.380317354886771,36.19827799340581,123 -5.380317354886771,36.19827799340581,123 -5.363435325517715,36.20339910102748,123 -5.363435325517715,36.20339910102748,123 -5.345878601074219,36.205128287456276,123 -5.345878601074219,36.205128287456276,123 -5.3283218766307225,36.20339910102748,123 -5.3283218766307225,36.20339910102748,123 -5.311439847261665,36.19827799340581,123 -5.311439847261665,36.19827799340581,123 -5.29588127988815,36.18996176588523,123 -5.29588127988815,36.18996176588523,123 -5.282244081528993,36.178770006425545,123 -5.282244081528993,36.178770006425545,123 -5.27105232206931,36.16513280806639,123 -5.27105232206931,36.16513280806639,123 -5.262736094548725,36.14957424069287,123 -5.262736094548725,36.14957424069287,123 -5.257614986927059,36.132692211323814,123 -5.257614986927059,36.132692211323814,123 -5.255885800498265,36.11513548688032,123 -5.255885800498265,36.11513548688032,123 -5.255885800498265,36.11513548688032,123  </coordinates>
                </LinearRing>
            </outerBoundaryIs>
        </Polygon>
    </Placemark>
</Document>
```

What I need is the polygon from `clampToGround` lifted 123 meters. Is this possible with google earth’s kml files. If so, how do I do that?
Thanks in advance!

EDIT: It was already reported as an issue: https://code.google.com/p/kml-samples/issues/detail?id=432

Answer (score 0):

There is a distinct behavioral difference between `clampToGround` and `relativeToGround` as defined in the KML specification.

**clampToGround** by definition follows the terrain such that a polygon will wrap the surface of a mountain or hill if it intersects with the terrain.

**relativeToGround** on the other hand creates a plane parallel to the ground that slices through any mountains and hills as seen in the Figure below. A relativeToGround of 123 meters is a ground elevation of 123 above the ground not above the top of the rock. The relative to ground zero elevation is this instance is the base of the rock.

[image: KML polygon rendering with relativeToGround altitudeMode]

The Rock of Gibraltar is approximately 390 meters above the ground at the summit so a relative elevation of 123 meters slices through the rock. If you want the polygon to be 123 meters above the tip of the rock then you should make the relative altitude ~513 meters which would be like a low-hanging green cloud over that location.

Alternatively, if you want the top of the rock wrapped with a green polygon and the plane of the polygon elevated at 123 meters (slicing through the rock) then suggest you define a [MultiGeometry](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#multigeometry) with the second polygon with relativeToGround (as listed above) and a smaller circle just covering the tip of the rock with altitudeMode=clampToGround.

```
<MultiGeometry>
 <Polygon>
  <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
  ... use coordinates of original polygon here
 </Polygon>
 <Polygon>
  <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
  ... use coordinates of smaller polygon here
 </Polygon>
</MultiGeometry>
```

But if you want the clampToGround behavior with the polygon following the shape of terrain, but elevated above ground then you'd need to create small meshes of polygons each in relativeToGround mode.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that is not really what I want. I want the polygon to be 123 meters above the ground at every point of the polygon, the polygon must follow the terrain but at an height of 123m above it. So at the top of the rock the polygon will be at an altitude of 513 meters and down above the sea the altitude will only be 123 meters. At first I thought `tessellate` would help with that but it won't. I could tessellate the polygon myself but it will be slow and I will need to create very small polygons to make it look good.

Comment: Tessellate is applicable only to clampToGround mode. Updated the answer. See if helps.

Comment: If want 123 meters entirely above the rock tip's elevation then make the elevation 123 above the tip which is about 513. But if truly want clampToGround but elevated above ground then you'd need to create a series of small patches or sub-meshes at 123. The smaller polygons will be relative to the ground under it on the rock and not at the sea level.

Comment: I truly want the clampToGround elevated above the ground and I hoped I wouldn't have to create sub-meshes but that google would do that for me with one of the altitude modes. Thanks for the help.